# Relationship between DFT input sequence and magnitude

Tags: dft, magnitude

Assuming there is a sequence that could look like this:

$$ x[n] = \{1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0,1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0,1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0\} $$

Using this sequence, I want to perform a DFT manually, the connection between $x[n]$ and $|X[k]|$ is important to me.

Now there is only one problem: my sequence contains 32 values, so the DFT by hand would be very complicated. Is there a faster way to see the connection/relationship between the original signal (sequence) $x[n]$ and the magnitude $|X[k]|$.

One can recognize a period in the sequence, perhaps that could be exploited, the question being, how?

To make it short: Assuming I have a sequence (e.g. the above given), how can I infer the magnitude $|X[k]|$ from it?

I hope my question is understandable so far. Thanks for coming answers!

Answer (score 1):

In general, one can't *infer* the magnitude of the DFT coefficients from the values of the input sequence if by inference one means a process that is much more amenable to manual computing than just evaluating the DFT directly. In a sense, you are asking for "half" (or more) of the information that the DFT provides without doing much work for it; TANSTAAFL. What *can* be done easily is to get a (weak) upper bound (in some sense, a trivial upper bound) on $|X[k]|$. We have that
\begin{align}
|X[k]| &= \left|\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} x[n]\exp(-j2\pi kn/N)\right|\\
&\leq \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \left|x[n]\exp(-j2\pi kn/N)\right|\\
&\leq \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \left|x[n]\right|\\
&\leq N \max_n |x[n]|.
\end{align}
In typical cases of DFT computations, this is a very weak bound. In the 
OP's special case however, one can use the fact that $16$ of the $32$ $x[n]$ are $0$ (and the rest have value $1$) to tweak the bound to 
$$|X[k]| \leq 16.$$
Since jomegaaA's calculations show that $X[0]$ does indeed have value $16$ in this instance, no tighter bound can be found in this particular instance.

Comment: I think your answer is very good and together with the amount spectrum that jomegaA has determined, it seems to fit. But assuming my sequence is (seq. 2 $x[n]=\{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0\}$, then the magnitude spectrum here would be another (maybe similar), how could I distinguish between the sequences or between the magnitude spectra? I would be interested in the assignment of sequence 1 and 2 to the corresponding magnitude spectra. In short:Say I have both sequences and both spectra, how can I assign them to each other (without knowing the relationship)?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really see any relation that gives an idea about magnitude of spectrum after transformation of a discrete sequence.

[image: FFT of a given sequence]

FFT of your sequence

Answer (score 0):

@Dilip Sarwate

Do I miss anything in the equation

$$\left|X[k]\right| = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \left| x[n]\right|$$

and its bit inconsistent to what follows after above equation

*I can't comment yet so I need to post as an answer

Comment: You did not miss anything.   The whole multiline expression is supposed to be a single-line statement and in the middle, we find $$|X(k)| \leq\cdots \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \left|x[n]\exp(-j2\pi kn/N)\right| = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \left|x[n]\right| \leq \cdots$$. I am not claiming what you think I am. But I will edit my answer to eliminate doubts.